# Inject Keysym (not keycode) into X11 Server

Tags: c, keyboard, x11, inject

I need to know how to inject a `KeySym` into the X Server using `xcb`, `xtest` or `xlib`. I can inject keycodes, also get the keyboard mapping, search for a keysym there and press the according keycode, but i cannot inject a KeySym (e.g. `XKB_KEY_Arabic_0`) when its not mapped to the current layout.

Is there a way I can do that?

What I thought of is find an empty keycode and remap it to the desired keysym. Problem: My code doesnt find an empty key. This is my code:

```
uint32_t find_empty_key_for_remapping()
{
    int keycode_low;
    int keycode_high;
    KeySym * keysyms = 0;
    int empty_key = 0;
    int num_keysym;
    XDisplayKeycodes(display_, &keycode_low, &keycode_high);
    keysyms = XGetKeyboardMapping(display_, keycode_low, keycode_high - keycode_low, &num_keysym);
    for (int i = keycode_low; i <= keycode_high && !empty_key; ++i)
    {
        bool key_is_empty = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_keysym; ++j)
        {
            int symindex = ((i - keycode_low) * num_keysym) + j;
            if (keysyms[symindex] != 0)
            {
                key_is_empty = false;
            }
        }
        if (key_is_empty)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use XChangeKeyboardMapping and add extra keycodes. You would need to do that each time the mapping changes.

Comment: Can I really add new keycodes? I thought you can just remap existing ones?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why not. Need to experiment.

Comment: As the keycode is an `uint8_t` and there exist 256 (0 - 255) of them, I dont think that creating keycode 256 will be successful. First I tried to seek for an unset keycode, but I dont unerstand the mapping in X when multiple keyboard layouts are set (then one keycode has up to 15 fields, all reachable via layout + modifier)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you cannot add keycodes.

Answer (score -1):

Injecting keysyms is done with `xdotool`. To insert `XKB_KEY_Arabic_0` use

```
xdotool key Arabic_0
```

which is independent of the keyboard mapping.

Comment: Its done with `xdotool` only if you do not want to incorporate it into your own program. As written in the question, the X11 C-Libraries are to be used. So this is not an answer to this question.